# Automatic import of CSV files to Access table

Tags: csv, ms-access, vba

I'm trying to set up an automatic process that scans a particular network folder for new CSV files and then appends the data to a table in Access.

A new CSV is placed in the folder everyday and they all have the same naming convention - `ClosingPrice_ddmmyy` with the date part changing on every file.

What's the most straight forward way to set up such a process?

All suggestions welcome!

Comment: Use `docmd.transferspreadsheet` method with timer event. Review these links [Link1](https://access-programmers.co.uk/forums/showthread.php?t=224155), [Link2](http://access-excel.tips/access-vba-cocmd-transferspreadsheet/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the reply, Rahul.
I found the following code on another forum that does most of what I want. It imports all the CSVs from within the source folder and adds them to a table within Access. However, in future I just want to add new CSVs that are added to the folder and not all the CSVs every time. Any ideas on how I can change the code to do this?

Thanks,

```
Sub Import_CSV()
     'Modified from WillR - www.willr.info (December 2004)
     
    Const strPath As String = "C:\ImportFolder\" 'Directory Path
    Dim strFile As String 'Filename
    Dim strFileList() As String 'File  Array
    Dim intFile As Integer 'File Number
     
     'Loop through the folder & build file list
    strFile = Dir(strPath & "*.csv")
    While strFile <> ""
         'add files to the list
        intFile = intFile + 1
        ReDim Preserve strFileList(1 To intFile)
        strFileList(intFile) = strFile
        strFile = Dir()
    Wend
     'see if any files were found
    If intFile = 0 Then
        MsgBox "No files found"
        Exit Sub
    End If
     'cycle through the list of files &  import to Access
     'creating a new table called MyTable
    For intFile = 1 To UBound(strFileList)
        DoCmd.TransferText acImportDelimi, ImportSpec, _
        "Raw Data", strPath & strFileList(intFile), -1
         'Check out the TransferSpreadsheet options in the Access
         'Visual Basic Help file for a full description & list of
         'optional settings
    Next
    MsgBox UBound(strFileList) & " Files were Imported"
End Sub
```

Comment: if you want to import each file into a separate table using filename as table name replace "Raw Data" with Left(strFileList(intFile),Len(strFileList(intFile)-4)